# Multiple condition in JMeter if controller

Tags: jmeter

Following condition in if controller is not working

(${__threadNum} =="1" || ${__threadNum} % 5 == "0")  && ("${__iterationNum}"=="1")

Comment: what's not working? have you tried to add quotation in first condition as ("${__threadNum}" =="1" || ${__threadNum} % 5 == "0") && ("${__iterationNum}"=="1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have types mismatch in your expression, you should amend it to:

```
(${__threadNum} ==1 || ${__threadNum} % 5 == 0) && ${__iterationNum} == 1
```

Also make sure you have [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) bundle installed, it can be done using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Custom Functions]

In case of any problems take a look at *jmeter.log* file, it should contain all necessary troubleshooting information.

Comment: Still it is failing and not executing the requests inside the if controller.

Answer (score 0):

need to put double quotes... ""

```
"${__threadNum}"==1 :::

("${__threadNum}"==1 ||"${__threadNum}"==0)&&("${__iterationNum}"==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi My answer may be helpful for someone else as well

```
${__groovy(vars.get("country) != "${Current_Country}" || vars.get("State") != "${__V(State_${Counter})}")}
```

Comment: Not sure you can use "" inside the __groovy function.
At least I got exception running jmeter 5.5